# Does nhibernate generate prepared statements when targeting Postgres via npgsql?

Tags: postgresql, nhibernate, npgsql

If it does, is there a way to query the database to confirm that the prepared statements are being generated, and see how much memory the prepared statements are consuming?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can check whether prepared statements exist on your connection by querying the [pg_prepared_statements system view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-prepared-statements.html). Any prepared statement should show up as a row there. Take care to query pg_prepared_statements on the same connection you're interested in checking. I'm not aware of any way of knowing how much memory the statements are consuming though.

If NHibernate *doesn't* prepare statements, you may want to check out Npgsql 3.2's new automatic preparation feature. When activated (it's off by default), Npgsql will track statements and automatically prepare frequently-used ones. See [Npgsql's performance docs](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/performance.html) for more information.